# Android Minesweeper project(from codeproject.com)

Tags: android

[Here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/113892/Minesweeper-Minesweeper-game-for-Android) is the link of the Minesweeper project on codeproject.com. 
I just wanted to ask one thing here. I completely understood the logic and algorithm this guy used, but when he called the showMineField() method inside startNewGame() method , he called it after createMineField(). I am really confused! Shouldn't the layout be set before setting up mines and handling the user click events? But the code seems to work fine. If I just call showMineField() inside startNewGame() , it gives me NullPointerException.

Comment: You probably should as the author, Manoj Kumar (great work!). Anyway, there's a complete block diagram illustrating the application life cycle.

Comment: Yes I know , I completely understood the game algorithm he used , its great work , but I just have that doubt I asked in the question. sowMineField() is just setting up the layout , and if I call just that , it gives me an exception, it has really started to bugging me now.

Comment: Well, I must be honest: I didn't scavenge the source in search of the logic. But let me SUPPOSE  what is he doing from your description. He's probably disposing the mines (populating the game board) each time the user wants to start a new game in createMineField(). Then he shows the newly created board in showMineField(). If you show the mine field without creating it, it probably refers not yet existing objects. Let's put it so: `you can't shoot a chicken before it came out of its egg`.

Comment: At least, if you want to eat chicken.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you cannot show a mine field before creating all the objects. 
It is like trying to run without legs. If you call showMineField() that is using objects that have not been initialized. Thats why you are recieving a NUllPointerException. Nullpointer is throws when a method is trying to be call on an object that has not been created yet. createminefield() initialzes everything so that nullpointer is not thrown